# seperate and get just some specific widget codes from kendo.all.js

Tags: kendo-ui, widget, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I'm new in kendo and search alot in net about quastion . have problem with my site loading performance . my big deal is using kendo.all, that I had to do because I use kendo chart and some widgets . so I should put kendo.web.js and kendo.dataviz.js with this arange :

```
 <script src="js/kendo/js/kendo.dataviz.min.js"></script>
 <script src="js/kendo/js/kendo.web.min.js"></script>
```

I could see chart but no data ...
therefore I had to use kendo.all while I'm using just 5 widgets and 2 charts or I don't need kendo mobile files. 
please tell how can I seperate these specific thing . is it posible at all??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can download the all the widget's separate JS file from [this](http://www.telerik.com/download/kendo-ui) link.
Inside the JS folder specific widgets JS file is available.

I have also attached screenshot for more detail. 
[image]

It might be possible that some of the JS file not available in trial version.